# How to install newer versions of the Linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, software-installation

A new version of the Linux kernel, 3.4, has been released today. How do I install it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Warning.

This can break your system. The  NVIDIA and ATI/AMD drivers and the broadcom wireless will most likely not work on this yet.

**I would advise against it** but if things get messed up you should be able to fix it by booting an old kernel and removing this one. Something like this ...

```
Boot from CD
mount -o bind /dev  /dev
mount -o bind /proc  /proc
chroot 
apt-get install 
update-grub
```

From comment by [Tomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/30451/tomas) an easier method:

- By entering GRUB through holding shift during boot you can enter the "Previous versions" of Linux. There you can select your old kernel, which is by default not removed.

> - Now if you still want it ...

Download the three .DEB files with the name starting with `linux` from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/

Example for i386 (take the 2 with `amd64` in the name for 64-bit and `pae` in the name for i386 with 4+Gb memory; check `uname -a` if you are unsure!):

```
linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb
linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
```

> - Install all 3 packages ...

Example for i386

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.4.0-030400_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_all.deb    
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.4.0-030400-generic_3.4.0-030400.201205210521_i386.deb
```

> - Reboot your system ...

```
sudo reboot
```

> - Test it ...

```
uname -r
```

This should show a kernel with 3.4 in the name.

> - [Now for the good news](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4) ...

- "This release includes several Btrfs updates: metadata blocks bigger than 4KB,
- much better metadata performance,
- better error handling and
- better recovery tools.
- a new X32 ABI which allows to run in 64 bit mode with 32 bit pointers;
- several updates to the GPU drivers: early modesetting of Nvidia Geforce 600 'Kepler', support of AMD RadeonHD 7xxx and AMD Trinity APU series, and support of Intel Medfield graphics;
- support of x86 cpu driver autoprobing, a device-mapper target that stores cryptographic hashes of blocks to check for intrusions, another target to use external read-only devices as origin source of a thin provisioned LVM volume,
- several perf improvements such as GTK2 report GUI and
- a new 'Yama' security module."
- You can help test official 3.4 support in 12.04 by following these instructions: http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/06/call-for-testing-1210-kernel-on-1204.html

Comment: But when this installation failes or Ubuntu will perform worse, I can still use older kernels right? I can choose them in the bootmenu.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Yes, you can always use older kernels!!!?? What "bad things"?

Comment: @Rinzwind they are outdated.

Comment: @Rinzwind: change your links to everything from here http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4-precise/  -- that's the official release! :)

Comment: Great answer, Rinzwind. Could you clarify the risks a bit or, as @izx said, state in your answer that this is completely reversible?  I'd do it myself if this wasn't way over my head :)

Comment: Just tried your method, works like a charm. As a side note to your answer: I think that recovering from a messed up kernel is easier than you describe. By entering GRUB through holding shift during boot you can enter the "Previous versions" of Linux. There you can select your old kernel, which is by default not removed.

Comment: @tomas I included it *O*

Comment: When will linux kernal 3.4 will show up in moun updater of kubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @ravi Ubuntu 12.10. 12.04 will -not- get 3.4

Comment: @Rinzwind Hi, can you tell me the reason?

Comment: @ravi cuz 12.04 is frozen. 12.10 is being developed.

Comment: @ravi because making a big change to a previous version of Ubuntu doesn't make sense.  It's risky for people who depend on it, and it'll come through in 12.10 anyway once it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu (32-bit) Generic:**

Run the following commands:

1.Create Folder for kernel

```
mkdir kernel3.4.1stable && cd kernel3.4.1stable
```

2.Download Kernel

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_i386.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.4.1-030401_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_all.deb 

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-image-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_i386.deb
```

**Extra Package**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_i386.deb
```

3.Install Kernel

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb 

sudo update-grub
```

**Ubuntu (64-bit):**

Run the following commands:

1.Create Folder for kernel

```
mkdir kernel3.4.1stable && cd kernel3.4.1stable
```

2.Download Kernel

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-headers-3.4.1-030401_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-image-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_amd64.deb
```

**Extra Package**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.1-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.4.1-030401-generic_3.4.1-030401.201206041411_amd64.deb
```

3.Install Kernel

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb 

sudo update-grub
```

**Extra Package?**
- It contains extra drivers left out of the base kernel package; install it only if you need these drivers.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Go into Terminal and type each of these commands to upgrade to latest 3.5 kernel AND newest nvidia drivers:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If something doesn't work properly or you just wish to go back to the old kernel then type these:

```
 sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

 sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```