# Xubuntu kernel upgrade to 3.4

Tags: kernel, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Linux 3.4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140254/how-to-install-linux-3-4)

I see that the 3.4 stable kernel was released a couple days ago. I'm looking for some onformation on how to upgrade from my 3.2.0-24-generic on my MSI Wind netbook. The reason for this is that I have several problems with XFCE freezing after wakeup, among a couple others I simply couldn't figure out. My question is, A. is it worth to upgrade? B. how would I go about doing that?

Thank you for your answer