# Update to 3.13 kernel on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: kernel, radeon, hybrid-graphics

Since my ATI hybrid graphics card isn't working well under Linux, I wanted to try the new kernel. I don't want to update to  14.04 just yet, because of some missing dependencies and there doesn't seem to be a kernel for 13.10 in the Ubuntu mainline (kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). Is there another way to install the new kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating is quite easy, from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/140263/38150) from [Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind):

Download the three .DEB files with the name starting with `linux` from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.13-trusty/).

Example for i386 (take the 2 with `amd64` in the name for 64-bit. Check `uname -a` if you are unsure):

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-031300_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_all.deb
linux-headers-3.13.0-031300-generic_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_i386.deb
linux-image-3.13.0-031300-generic_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_i386.deb
```

> - Install all 3 packages ...

Example for i386

```
dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.0-031300_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-headers-3.13.0-031300-generic_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_i386.deb
dpkg -i linux-image-3.13.0-031300-generic_3.13.0-031300.201401192235_i386.deb
```

or

```
 dpkg -i *.deb
```

> - Reboot your system ...

I just this and it resulted in disc failure. But I fixed it using:

```
fsck /dev/<disk> -y
```