# Ubuntu 3.13 Kernel update not working

Tags: kernel, graphics

I started on Linux a week ago. My friend hooked me up with it and I started with **Kernel 3.10**. I'm trying to update to **3.13**, but when I try to install it through the terminal it won't go past **3.11**.

What would be the easiest way to diagnose the problem and get it updated properly? I might mention that my graphics card is an **R9 280x**, but my system won't recognize it, it says I have a **7970**.

Comment: If you've just started with Linux why do you want to upgrade the kernel yourself? Why don't you wait till it's pushed out to regular users?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 3.10?It's ages since it has been removed.or maybe you are messing up with Ubuntu version and kernel version.They are both different.The officially provided(i.e provided bu Ubuntu repositories) Linux kernel is currently 3.11.It is better that you wait until 3.13(or any newer version) is officially released.Currently,you may update to version 3.11

Comment: @adityapatil, OP may have meant 13.10 ;)

Comment: I rather think he has messed between kernel version and Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, 3.13 kernel is currently available only for 14.04 (still in development)

Ubuntu 13.10 has reach Kernel 3.11

Check here last packages of Liunx in all releases https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install a kernel version which is not in repository. Since **kernel 3.13** stable version is just released.

But that's not the problem. You can still install it from other ways.

I'm listing a way to install. Also I'm attaching some links which would be helpful to install latest kernels.

Execute these command in terminal to install Linux Kernel 3.13:

```
mkdir linux-3.13 && cd linux-3.13
wget http://goo.gl/x4JYAz -O kernel-3.13 
chmod +x kernel-3.13
sudo sh kernel-3.13 
sudo reboot
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2014/01/installupgrade-to-linux-kernel-313-in.html)</sub>

Also see these links:

- [How to install newer versions of the Linux kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140254/how-to-install-newer-versions-of-the-linux-kernel)
- [The Linux 3.13 Kernel Has Many Improvements](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTU2NDE)