# Where can i find linux 3.8.11 kernel image in order to build wacom drivers for Samsung Chromebook 2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, wacom

My setup: Samsung Chromebook 2 -> running Ubuntu via crouton (trusty with KDE).

I'm in the process of installing the Wacom Intuos drawing tablet, and I need to install the kernel driver for it since it is not working from the get go (I can see it in lsusb , but no input is working).

Following [this Input-wacom guide](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom)
But when I do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I just get a response that no such package could be found (uname -r = 3.8.11).

I found a post of a guy (divx118) that tried to create a kernel image (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/772#issuecomment-40894248),
but I get an error when trying to configure the wacom driver later on.
Is there anything I am missing here, can i get this 3.8.11 kernel image from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Try the ubuntu Kernel Mainline:

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

You'll find the latest and also previous kernel packages and sources. Also, try [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org), the official Linux Kernel repository.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to download the 3.8.13 header/image file. I install it with dpkg and everything seems fine, i reboot and uname -r still says 3.8.11 instead of 3.8.13. Checking the /lib/modules/ folder i can see that i have 2 folders for each version. How do i change it to load the 3.8.13 kernel instead?

Grub is not installed it seems? i guess that is just for dual boot and not crouton

Comment: At your boot screen check for others versions of Ubuntu. You should see both. Also did you update grub after the changes? If not try `sudo update-grub`. Also, check this post on how to install the kernel debs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140254/how-to-install-newer-versions-of-the-linux-kernel