# Install kernel headers 3.8.11

Tags: 16.04, kernel, linux-headers

It can't find the package linux-headers-3.8.11

I have confirmed that it is on 3.8.11 and I don't want to update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565765/where-can-i-find-linux-3-8-11-kernel-image-in-order-to-build-wacom-drivers-for-s) answer, you can search the [Ubuntu Kernel Mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). Do be warned: Ubuntu 16.04 is not meant to run the 3.8.* kernels, so unless you are absolutely unable to update, I would recommend doing so.