# Asus X555UB touchpad driver

Tags: drivers, touchpad, laptop, asus

I have an Asus notebook, model [X555UB](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/X555UB/). Unfortunately the touchpad doesn't work. Where can I find drivers?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What does `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update to the 4.4 kernel version (for this you can follow the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140254/how-to-install-newer-versions-of-the-linux-kernel)). This solved the problems with the touchpad i had on my asus X555UA, but i still have problems with the internl mic and the jack.

Comment: Works with kernel 4.3.0.5 (you can test it using ubuntu 16.04 live to be sure before install).
The hardware is Elan Touchpad. Thank you!